# Vuelidate firing multiple times on page load

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I'm using Vue, and for validations, [Vuelidate](https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate).

When using a custom validator that performs an AJAX call , **it is firing multiple times** on page load and even before user interaction(vuelidate's `$touch`).

After these multiple calls on first load, the validation works correctly. (I use this validation on input change, using vue `@change`)

I tried setting a flag `isMounted` to perform the validations inside de custom validator only after the whole instance is loaded, but without success.

**CODE**

The validator (only with debug, for testing):

```
validations() {
    return {
        myFieldToValidate(field) {
            test_validation(value) {
                console.log('test validation fired!', Math.random());
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when I reload the page, it is firing multiple times:

[image: multiple-calls]

I want to make the validation "fire" based only by my event(input change), not multiple times on page load. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended making my own function that makes the ajax call, separating from `vuelidate`. I used [lodash' _.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) to control the calls.

I binded the function to the `@input` event, make the `ajax` call based on it and returned a "flag" attribute with the result.

Then, I use this flag to check the validity of the field.

Using this abordage, the event is not firing multiple times on page load.

Answer (score 0):

`@change.once` should do the trick

see the link for more information
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-once

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This just executed the event one time, but what I want is that it not execute the first time(page load), but keep executing in the next times(change event)